# No value has been specified for property 'command', gradle node plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-node-plugin

```
task  npmInstallPkg(type: NpxTask){
    doLast{
        //install node packages from package.json
        dependsOn npmInstall

        //install pkg globally
        command = 'npm'
        args = ['install', '-g', 'pkg']
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to execute the above task, I get below error :

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':npmInstallPkg'.
> No value has been specified for property 'command'.
```

I am using the **"com.github.node-gradle.node"** plugin version **"2.2.4"**.

I have cross checked the syntax multiple times and haven't been able to find anything wrong with it.
I created the task by referencing the plugin documentation at https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/2.2.4/docs/node.md#executing-npm-commands-via-npx

My node cofiguration block is as follows :

```
// gradle node plugin configuration
node {
  // Version of node to use.
  version = '10.14.1'

  // Version of npm to use.
  npmVersion = '6.4.1'

  // Version of Yarn to use.
  yarnVersion = '1.3.2'

  // Base URL for fetching node distributions (change if you have a mirror).
  distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'

  // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
  // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
  download = true

  // Set the work directory for unpacking node
  workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")

  // Set the work directory for NPM
  npmWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/npm")

  // Set the work directory for Yarn
  yarnWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/yarn")

  // Set the work directory where node_modules should be located
  nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the error is because the gradle-node-plugin is not able to find the property `command` for `npmInstallPkg` of type `NpxTask`, which it expected while configuring the task itself. The only solution that worked for me was removing the `doLast` block.

But not being able to define the `command` in the `doLast` seemingly takes away the charge from me in that I am no more able to stop it from executing during the configuration phase. Ideally I would have wanted this to be able to execute during execution phase or when I manually called it.

Though this solves my original issue, I am still looking for a way to call the task during execution phase.